# Jenkins free style project: how to print Groovy's html variables

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

How to print Groovy's html variables in Execute shell section.

```
if(DB_DUMP_TYPE.equals("EXPDB")){
def FullHTML = """
<label style="left: 22%; position: absolute;">DB_WALLET_LOC</label>
<input name='DB_WALLET_LOC1' type='text' value='hello'> </input><br>
"""
return FullHTML
}
```

I've tried to print in "DB_WALLET_LOC1" value in Execute shell section with the following option :

%$DB_WALLET_LOC1%
${DB_WALLET_LOC}

But it in not printing the value.

Is there any other syntax that we need to use ?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject this value into environment by check `Prepare an environment for the run`,
and put following script into `Groovy script` input box.

```
...
DB_DUMP_TYPE = ...

if(DB_DUMP_TYPE == "EXPDB"){
  def FullHTML = """
  <label style="left: 22%; position: absolute;">DB_WALLET_LOC</label>
  <input name='DB_WALLET_LOC1' type='text' value='hello'> </input><br>
  """
  return ['FullHTML': FullHTML]
}
```

[image]

Then you can **print out** the value in Shell as following:

[image]